# Best way to fetch data from SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm making an application which uses weather API so that when person enters zipcode, it shows the detailed weather conditions of a particular area. If my zipcode is valid, then I save my zipcode so that when I start my application next time, I have list of all zipcodes which I saved(All zipcodes populate in listview).  I use SQLite database to save my zipcode

Presently, I'm using AsyncTask to query my database, get all the rows and show it in listview. But I feel that it is not the best way to query the database and obtain result. Can any one tell me the best and most efficient strategy which should be used to query SQLite database and show result in listview. I think I need to use loaders.

Thanks

Comment: Use CursorAdapter : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do AsyncTask for database related work,

you simply connect to database from your activity

```
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 Cursor c;
 ListView lv1;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Wheather(Report VARCHAR)");
 c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Wheather",null);
 int count = c.getCount();
 String values[] = new String[count+1];
 int i = 0;
 while(c.moveToNext())
 { 
   values[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Report"));
   i++;
 }
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1,values);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What if there is a lot of data in your database. You do not want to block your main thread if you open database on it.

Comment: yeah in that case you have to use loader

Comment: you can use custom Loaders

Comment: Do I need to use AsyncTask loader or cursor loader. I googled implementations of loaders with sqlite database. Some of them have made a custom content provider and then used CursorLoader. According to android developer guide, it clearly says not to use content provider with sqlite if you are using that data only within your application.

Comment: Android provides a ‘CursorLoader’ class which can read data from content providers but to read data directly from the SQLite database we need our own custom loader. link is here http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-loader-to-load-data-directly-from-sqlite-database.html